# My Submitpost function isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebase

First time using angularJs and I'm following an AngularJS reddit clone tutorial and I don't know where I went wrong.  When I click the submit button nothing happens.  https://github.com/Eibonic/AngularJS-reddit/tree/master/app

This is the nav.js controller

```
    'use strict';

app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Post, Auth) 
{
$scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};

$scope.submitPost = function () 
{
    Post.create($scope.post).then(function (ref) 
    {
        $scope.post = {url: 'http://', title: ''};
        $location.path('/posts/' + ref.name());
        });
        };

});
```

This is the nav.html view file.

```
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
   <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">
   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">ang-news</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div ng-controller="NavCtrl" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" ng-submit="submitPost()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" ng-model="post.title">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Link"      ng-model="post.url">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
 </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the github project you linked, there were two issues; I found both of them by running the project and opening the debug console in Chrome.

`Unknown provider: AuthProvider <- Auth <- NavCtrl` In English, this means that you attempted to inject the `Auth` provider (which doesn't exist) as a dependency in the NavCtrl. This is on line 3 of nav.js. You aren't actually using the Auth service yet, so just removing it from your function declaration fixes it. It should look like this:

```
app.controller('NavCtrl', function ($scope, $location, Post)
```

Once you get to the point in the tutorial where you create the Auth provider you'll be able to inject it here.

The second error was `GET http://localhost:9000/scrips/controllers/postview.js 404`

This means that the HTML attempted to load the postview.js script, but couldn't find it. Turns out there was a typo in index.html on line 89 when loading the script. It should be `http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/postview.js` (Missing the 't' in 'scripts')

After making those two changes it seems to be working fine now.

Comment: Thanks you fixed everything, also is there any advice on how to make my questions better for next time?  I'd like to make answering them less troublesome.

Comment: Glad I could help! Some things you could do better: Include any error messages that display in the debug console. (You can access this in chrome by right clicking on the page, selecting "inspect element" and clicking on the "console" tab of the window that pops up). It would also be helpful for you to format your code to be more readable. Formatting makes it easier for you (and others) to read your code.